# Unable to upload Image to backend using multer

Tags: node.js, express, file, file-upload, multer

I was working on a small project on backend using nodeJS. I want to upload image to backend. I'm using nodeJS for backend and using packages like express, body-parser & multer.

I build a simple project to upload image, for now I just want that image is uploaded & stored in "public" folder that is in same level as server.js

**server.js file**

```
const express = require('express')
const multer= require('multer')
const path= require('path')
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const app = express()

const storage= multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,"public")
    },
    filename: (req,file,cb)=>{
        console.log(file);
        cb(null, Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname);
    }
})
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) );
const uploads= multer({storage:storage})

app.post('/upload', uploads.single('image'), (req, res){
        res.sendFile(req.file) // just send back json data of file that is uploaded
})

app.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'./index.html'))
});

app.listen(8000, ()=> console.log('Server Running at port: 8000'))
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also created a 'public' folder for storing files. Tried all possible ways available, read official document, watched videos but I'm unable to get it right. When I'm sending a post request I'm able to get data as req.body but I'm not getting req.file, I want to take the file that is uploaded in post request and save it in public folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting up `destination` path with `path` module, like on the GET route below.

try this:

```
const express = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'public'))
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
    }
})
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
const uploads = multer({
    storage: storage
})

app.post('/upload', uploads.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    console.log('uploaded:', req.file);
    res.sendFile(req.file.path);
    // or
    //res.download(req.file.path);
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server Running at port: 8000'))
```